# How does this interleaving recursive function work?

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, nested-function

I'm trying to understand exactly how this recursive function works. I know that it takes two lists and interleaves them. Could someone enlighten me about the nested part of the function?

```
def interleave(lst):
    def interleaveHelper(lst1,lst2):
        if not lst1:
            return lst2
        elif not lst2:
            return lst1
        return lst1[0:1] + interleaveHelper(lst2, lst1[1:])
    return interleaveHelper(lst[:len(lst)/2], lst[len(lst)/2:])
```

Comment: Have you tried executing it and seeing the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive nested function just takes the first element of the first argument, then swaps the arguments for the recursive call (minus that first element).

So given a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the outer call splits the list in two and the recursion then does:

```
([1, 2], [3, 4]) -> [1] + ([3, 4], [2])
    ([3, 4], [2]) -> [3] + ([2], [4])
        ([2], [4]) -> [2] + ([4], [])
            ([4], []) -> return [4]  # lst2 is empty, return lst1
        return [2] + [4]
    return [3] + [2, 4]
return [1] + [3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are actually **two different things** defined and being used here. `interleaveHelper` will take the first elemente from the *first* list and then apply teh same function recursively but with the lists swapped. That means, that the next call it will take out the first element of the *second* list.

Now that this is clarified, you should see the other function: `interleave`. This function takes **one list** and split it at the half (see the last line) by slicing (for instance, `lst[:len(lst)/2]` is the first half). Then it takes the two halves and interleave them.

This means that the function will shuffle the items in a similar way as you shuffle the cards: split in halves and mix them one by one.  :-)

A simple example would be:

```
In [2]: a = range(10)

In [3]: interleave(a)
Out[3]: [0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The interleave function is really `interleaveHelper(l1, l2)`. Assume that you have 2 lists `l1=[1,2,3]` and another `l2=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` as an example. Also lets call `interleaveHelper(l1, l2) = f(l1,l2)` for brevity. Then, the last line will give:

```
f([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) = [1] + f(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [2,3])
                                 = [1] + ['a'] + f([2,3], ['b', 'c', 'd']) 
                                 = [1, 'a'] + f([2,3], ['b', 'c', 'd'])
                                 = [1, 'a'] + [2] + f(['b', 'c', 'd'], [3])
                                 = [1, 'a', 2] + f(['b', 'c', 'd'], [3])
                                 = [1, 'a', 2] + ['b'] + f([3], ['c', 'd'])
                                 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b'] + f([3], ['c', 'd'])
                                 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b'] + [3] + f(['c', 'd'], [])
                                 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3] + f(['c', 'd'], [])
                                 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3] + ['c', 'd']
                                 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 'd']
```

I think its very easy to understand in this way ...